# Where are the implementation of stack functions?

Tags: c++, stack

I am learning `data structures and algorithms`. My teacher told me the following:

> push(): push inserts an element in the stack
>
> pop(): pop deletes the last inserted element from the stack
>
> size(): Returns the number of elements in the stack
>
> isempty(): Returns a boolean indicating if the stack is empty
>
> top(): returns the top element of the stack, without removing it; If stack is empty an error is returned.

**Where are the implementations** of these functions? Are these `built-in functions` of C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your teacher was explaining the functions available for the *generic stack data structure*. Those functions aren't implemented anywhere in particular because your teacher was not talking about any specific stack. Your teacher wasn't even talking about C++. Right now you're just learning about what a stack *is*: they're abstract data structures implementable in any language. They're last-in-first-out containers. Later in your course, you'll learn about *trees*, *queues*, *heaps*, *lists*, and all sorts of other abstract data structures. In a later lesson, your teacher will probably demonstrate how to implement the functions listed above. The demonstration might even be in C++.

Comment: I'm guessing you're right about the teachers intent, but his question was explicitly about C++.

Answer (score 5):

These are member functions for [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/), which is a container class (template) in the C++ standard library.

You can find the implementation in the `<stack>` header file.

[Note that it's `empty()`, not `isempty()`, though.]

Answer (score 1):

std::stack - it's in the standard library, which is "part" of c++, although it's not a "built-in function"

Answer (score 0):

To use the stl you would have to include all or part of it in your files, or reference the stl each time you use it.

Here is a link to an implementation of the STL:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html

Comment: While it's debatable whether the words 'standard template library' are applicable to C++, there's definitely no "stl::".

Comment: Oops.  Getting my languages mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out how to create your own template classes and functions, see

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

If you want to understand how a stack could be implemented, and what a stack *is*, read

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29

If you want to understand more about containers in C++ STL, read these:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Hopefully, these references will help you with asking a more specific question or to request clarification on something you don't yet understand...